# How do I configure a Router without a WAN Port to connect to the Internet?

Tags: networking, wireless-router

I'm in a dorm room where they only provide us with a single Ethernet cable. I have this TP-Link Modem/Router which has no WAN ports on it and I'm wondering if there is a clever way of using it as a wireless access point for all my devices?

Comment: What is the model of your TP-Link Modem/Router?

Comment: @sunk818 it has 4 LAN ports but no WAN ports!

Comment: @DavidPostill It is TD-W8961ND. Firmware Version: 5.0.0 Build 120522 Rel.23978

Comment: It's probably a DSL modem/router... You could do the usual set the router portion to not provide DHCP -> set the router to have a static IP (it will need to be outside the DHCP scope of your dorm ethernet cable - this is where you may run into problems) -> plug your other devices in and they should work... The problem will be your dorm ethernet configuration...

Comment: It is adsl modem router. Can't be used as you want.

Comment: @BigChris of course I even tried disabling DHCP and setting my laptop's IP on the router but to no avail. The range for dorm's HDCP pool is nothing I can tell, but I will try a few random IPs asap. It is just that Internet led on the router never shows any signs of hope.

Comment: @sunk818 and why would it make a difference?

Comment: You get an uplink and your router becomes a switch. Turn dhcp off on router, but let your laptop to get an ip from the university server via auto assigned ip

Comment: You'll never get an "Internet" LED light up with what you're trying to do... The "Internet" LED is only showing that the modem portion of the modem/router has a successful connection to your ISP. You're no longer using the DSL part of your device.

Comment: This Modem/Route comes with VLAN functionality and it also lets you add Custom Routes. Can't I just add two separate VLANs and somehow route internet packets from one to another?

Comment: @AllGreenPhosphor No. Just buy a crossover ethernet cable like I said, or go buy a router that has a WAN (uplink) port for the university connection to go to. You can buy an inexpensive used LinkSys router on eBay for $20.

Answer (score 1):

if the TP-LINK you have , really does not have a wan port , and it is a router as you say , then any port can be configured as a wan ,  yet you dont have to configure it as a router , just plug your TP-LINK to your PC , enable DHCP client on your PC  ( that can be found in network adapter properties in windows and it is enabled by default  )  and check what IP address had been given to you ,  if no IP address is given to you , ( do that on all the ports in the TP-LINK )  ,  that means it will be only switching frames on layer 2 ( as DHCP SERVER is OFF on the TP-LINK )  , which means you can plug you devices ( including WI-FI AP ) in any ports , and connect one of the ports to the Ethernet port you have in the dorm .

Answer (score 0):

A switch is what you want.

> A network switch (sometimes known as a switching hub) is a computer networking device that is used to connect devices together on a computer network, by using a form of packet switching to forward data to the destination device.

[image]

This will enable you to plug in the single ethernet cable to one of the ports, and use the other seven to connect to the internet. You can get them fairly cheaply, and the Netgear one above is not the only one available.

I know that this does not offer wireless capability, and incurs an extra cost, but it does offer many more ethernet ports.

Comment: How do you know that he has more than one address to use?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz That is a concern. If only IP is assigned per jack, then OP would need a router with an uplink then use DHCP to assign local IPs so it looks like the router is the only network device for the university network.

Comment: The fact is that I have no more than one IP.

Answer (score 0):

You gotta work on clarity.  What I understand is that your dorm provides an Ethernet outlet which as you say can be plugged into one computer.  All this means is that somewhere outside of your room there is a router assigning IP addresses to each room via the Ethernet port in those rooms.  So the routing AKA IP assigning is taking care for you.  What you have to do is connect your wireless router, that you say you have, to your computer, login to it, disable DHCP and assign it an IP Number.  The router that is providing one IP per dorm is absolutely clueless, because it's still giving you the one Public IP which it feeds to your wireless AP.  The IP address you give to the router is purely for managing the router.  Basically your wireless AP commmands the remote router to give it the Public IP, and it itself gives local IPs to each device. Once you have configured as I have said, you connect your ethernet to the WAN port of the wireless AP; why because just consider WAN to mean Public IP, you connect your computers to the other wired ports or wirelessly.  Once again your router provides local IPs to each device and the Public IP has been fed to your router by the offsite router/DHCP server; whereever it is in your building, perhaps even in another building.

Comment: PS. All wireless AP have WAN port.  The process that I describe works both with wired and wireless routers.  Finally, wireless routers are wired routers too.  If it doesn't have a WAN port it is not a router, and probably a switch.  You should be able to achieve the same with a switch because disabling DHCP on your router effectively makes it a managed switch.